# Test with chromedriver don't work in java application deployed on Heroku server

Tags: java, selenium, heroku, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a little Selenium WebDriver test for Vaadin app. With chromedriver, if tell it more exactly. In my app I have button "Play demo", which starts the app in new session of Chrome browser and execute some app testing tasks.

```
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); // am getting chromedriver with this WebDriverManager

        // After that:
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.navigate().to("https://pazukdevtestapp1.herokuapp.com");

        // Or so:
        driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.navigate().to("https://pazukdevtestapp1.herokuapp.com/#!Hotels");
```

When I start app from localhost - test starts and all works good with both of these two variants of code. Never mind, click on button run the app itself on localhost or the same app on Heroku server. 
But it not working if try to launch it from the app on server. Any ideas why it going this way?

PS App log on server:

```
2018-06-01T09:15:08.692373+00:00 app[web.1]: Jun 01, 2018 9:15:08           AM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
2018-06-01T09:15:08.692407+00:00 app[web.1]: SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.692918+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "Thread-14" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
2018-06-01T09:15:08.692921+00:00 app[web.1]: Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
2018-06-01T09:15:08.692931+00:00 app[web.1]: System info: host: '25cd720a-5a6d-4e75-b214-9d81aafe7880', ip: '172.16.177.98', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-1019-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_171-heroku'
2018-06-01T09:15:08.692994+00:00 app[web.1]: Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
2018-06-01T09:15:08.693054+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.694600+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:181)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.694661+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.694716+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.694798+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.694853+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.694938+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.694993+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:184)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.695049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:171)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.695133+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.695187+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.pazukdev.auxiliary_services.DemoService.prepareBrowser(DemoService.java:100)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.695276+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.pazukdev.auxiliary_services.DemoService.executeTasks(DemoService.java:63)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.695337+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.pazukdev.auxiliary_services.DemoService.access$000(DemoService.java:22)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.696501+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.pazukdev.auxiliary_services.DemoService$1.run(DemoService.java:39)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.696566+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.697012+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:32260/status] to be available after 20021 ms
2018-06-01T09:15:08.697192+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:107)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.697251+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:190)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.697305+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 14 more
2018-06-01T09:15:08.697708+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2018-06-01T09:15:08.697772+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:140)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.697878+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:80)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.698077+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 15 more
2018-06-01T09:15:08.698848+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
2018-06-01T09:15:08.698916+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.699230+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:128)
2018-06-01T09:15:08.699288+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 2):

First, and just to be sure, you have installed `chromedriver` on heroku using the heroku build packs? If not, you'll have to install them by including the following two buildpacks:

- [heroku-buildpack-google-chrome](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome)
- [heroku-buildpack-chromedriver](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver)

Next, note the end of the README for `heroku-buildpack-google-chrome` where it shows you how to get the path for `chromedriver` which you need to pass into `ChromeOptions`, which from what you've shown you haven't passed in.

Lastly, you're instantiating a new `ChromeOptions` object above, but from what you've shown you're not passing it to `ChromeDriver`, which you should do like:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

The reason you would see this working in your dev environment and not on heroku would probably be because `chromedriver` is installed somewhere where selenium expects to find it, but you need to explicitly path the location when running on heroku.

Comment: 1. Sorry, yes, ofcourse I meant driver = new ChromeDriver(options). In real code I have it right. I just made mistake here while was writing text of my question.

Comment: 2. No, I have not.I saw these links and these repositories for many times while was googleing for my issue. But I saw there code in unknown programming language (it's Ruby, if I understend it right) and I didn't saw there any Java code or anything about how to install it in Java-application. So, I thought that it is not applicable to Java applications. And I still don't see there any guide how implement these buildpacks to my application.